# stopping an animation on the spot

Tags: animation, ios4, uislider

i have a UISLider that is being animated - going across the screen over a 91.0 second period.
i would like to be able to stop the animation spot on.

the code:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:91.0
        delay:0.0
        options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|
                    UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|
            UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
        animations:^{[UIView setAnimationDuration:91.0];
                 [myUISlider setValue:91.0];}
            completion:nil];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

- one way to stop an animation is setting a new value. however, i cannot READ the current value/position of the slider DURING the animation. when accessing mySlider.value i get the target value (where the animation will end, i.e 91.

i did some digging up and came across the **continuous flag** which fires up an action method and is setup up to YES by default. from the developer reference:

"...if YES, the slider sends update events continuously to the associated target’s action method...".

however, the value here is, again, 91.0...

thank you for your time.

yours,

~nir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask the UISlider's layer for its `-presentationLayer`, you can then interrogate that copy of the layer for the near real-time animated properties. From the [CALayer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/presentationLayer):

> Returns a copy of the layer containing all properties as they were at the start of the current transaction, with any active animations applied.

Comment: thanx for your answer tjw. following up on your suggestion i found that this class provides information about the layer itself. for example, i was able to extract the position.x and position.y of the slider but not the current value of the slider point itself. thoughts?

Comment: Oops, I seem to have misunderstood your question. Perhaps you can amend your question to show how you are controlling the animation speed of the value. You are presumably calling -setValue:animated:, but that ignores the duration set in any enclosing UIView animation block.

Comment: thanks TJW, i just re-edited the post and added some code. i hope it will be clearer now what i am trying to achieve. thanks for your time.